# Form validation using typescript

Tags: html, typescript

I have a question. How can we make a field have unique values while doing form validation using html and typescript. For example, I want a field called patientID to have unique values when a user make an input. Thanks in advance

```
let id : number =  parseInt(idString); //convert idString to number
    if (isNaN(id)){
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "ID must be a number";
        return;
    }
    // if (id+ =id){
    //  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "ID must be a unique";

    // }
```

Comment: In the first line, you're converting id into a number and in the next line, you're checking if it's a string or not?!

Comment: There is nothing to deal with typescript. You can push the entered IDs into an Array and check if the ID has already been entered or not.